# How to get external 2.5 inch HD enclosure recognised

Tags: windows-7, enclosures, disk-management, desktop-computer

I am completely out of ideas.

I have 2.5inch HDD from my old laptop, I have tried with 2 different HDD enclosures but my desktop does not recognize it. Not even showing in the disk management or BIOS.

The HDD works fine if I use in a 3.5 inch enclosure with external power.

I have tried 3 different Y USB cables. I have also got a 7 port self powered 2A USB hub.

I have updated my chipset drivers as well.

The problem is with my desktop , the enclosures work fine with my new laptop.

Anything else that I should try?

The drive capacity is 160gb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question one must be "what OS"?

Comment: oops sorry, its windows 7 64 bit.